# regex jquery to replace number with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a page of database results where users occasionally type in a reference to another post. (The database is day event tracker for a scheduling office).

The reference to the other post is always the posts ID (format of 001234). We uses these to match events with dockets and other paperwork from truck drivers. It is always a 6 digit number on its own.

```
<div class="eventsWrapper">
 Data from DB is output here using PHP in a foreach loop.
 Presents data in similar fashion to facebook for example.
</div>
```

What I need to do is once the data in the above DIV is loaded, then go through and replace every whole 6 digit number (not part of a number) with the number as a hyperlink.

It is important it only looks for number with a space either side:

```
EG: Ref 001122 <- like this - not like this -> ignore AB001122
```

Once I have the hyperlink tag I can make the reference number clickable to take users directly to that post.

I am not that good with regex but think it is something like:

```
\b(![0-9])?\d{6}\b
```

I have no idea how to search the DIV and then replace that regex with the hyperlink. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^| )\d{6}(?= |$)
```

You can use this and replace by `<space><whateveryouwant>`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bW3aR1/7

`\b` wont works cos `A1` is not a `word boundary` which you want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?  Make an array of the individual posts and loop through.  If there is only ever one ID in a post, you can do without the second loop.

```js
var str = ['Ref 001122 <- like this - not like this -> ignore AB001122', 'Ref 001123 <- like this - not like this -> ignore AB001122', 'Ref 001124 <- like this - not like this -> ignore AB001122'];
var regex = /\b\d{6}\b/g;
for (var j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
  var urls = str[j].match(regex);
  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    var url = urls[i];
    newString = str[j].replace('' + urls[i] + '', '<a href = ' + url + '>' + urls[i] + '</a>')
  }
  $('#output').append(newString);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```